# AJAX response doesn't print in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

I am using AJAX to get form data from Django application and I want to print the response in the console.

```
    $.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET' ,               
    url: url,              
    data: {'PUITS': PUITSId },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response){
        console.log(response)
        var  response = JSON.stringify(response);
        var  response = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response.PUITS);
        console.log(response.DUSE);
        console.log(response.CS);
```

The first `console.log(response)` gives me the following data:

```
[{"model": "measure.surveillancedespuits", "pk": 15, "fields": {"PUITS": "1", "DATE_TEST": "2021-09-10", "MODE": "GL", "CS": "1", "SITUATION": "O", "DUSE": "27", "PRES_TBG": "27", "PRES_CSG": "27", "PRES_AVD": "27", "RESEAU_GL": "27", "ANNULAIRE_TECH": "27", "OBSERVATION": "Nothing", "Controle_Pression_ENSP": true, "Test_Puits": false, "Controle_Pression_DP": false, "post_date": "2021-09-10T08:56:16.864Z", "author": "smail"}}]
```

and I want to print also some individual data from `fields`  like `PUITS,` DATE_TEST`,` post_date` in the console but it shows an error!.

Comment: The response object is already parsed. You don't need to parse it again.

Comment: I deleted all parsing code and tried ( console.log(response.PUITS);  ) and it give me this  undefined message?

Comment: Maybe it's not there. Check you server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to your log result, your response is an array not an object.
you CANT access array elements using dot(.) operator.

your response array contains only one element at index 0.

```
const object = response[0]
object.fields.PUITS
```

Comment: I just add 
            var  response = JSON.parse(response);
            const object = response[0]
            console.log(object.fields.PUITS)

and it works many thanks